# Where is 'number' inferred from here?

Tags: typescript

I get a compilation error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{ G: string; C: string; T: string; A: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{ G: string; C: string; T: string; A: string; }'.(7053)
```

on `Transcriptor.DNA_TO_RNA_NUCLEOTIDES[dnsNucleotide]` in the following code:

```
class Transcriptor {

    static readonly DNA_TO_RNA_NUCLEOTIDES = { 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G', 'T': 'A', 'A': 'U' }

    toRna(dnaStrand: string) {
        let rnaStrand: string = ""
        const dnaAsArray: string[] = Array.from(dnaStrand)
        for (const dnsNucleotide in dnaAsArray) {
            const rnaNucleotide: string = Transcriptor.DNA_TO_RNA_NUCLEOTIDES[dnsNucleotide]
            rnaStrand += rnaNucleotide
        }
        return rnaStrand
    }
}

export default Transcriptor
```

I would understand that this happened if `dnsNucleotide` could be `any`, but in this case it's a `string`, so where is `number` being inferred from?

I know I can fix it with `static readonly DNA_TO_RNA_NUCLEOTIDES: { [key: string]: string} = {...}`

Comment: `for (const var in arr) {` iterates over the *indices* of an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: [...`for...in` statement, but for iterating arrays for-in should be avoided, that statement is meant to enumerate object properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/542251)

Comment: @jonrsharpe but if I hover with the mouse over `const dnsNucleotide`, the IDE (VS Code) tells me that it's of type `string`

Comment: I'm not sure why, you can see with e.g. `for (const val in ["foo", "bar", "baz"]) { console.log(val) }` that you get `0`, `1`, `2`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I also don't understand how, if the problem is how I iterate the array, `static readonly DNA_TO_RNA_NUCLEOTIDES: { [key: string]: string}` solves the problem.